# PhpStorm code completion based on parameters

Tags: phpstorm

I am wondering, if it's possible to have code completion based on parameters passed to a method.

Example:

```
class One { public function foo(){} }
class Two { public function bar(){} }
class DI {
    public function get($name) {
        if ($name === 'foo') {
            return new One();
        } elseif ($name === 'bar') {
            return new Two();
        }
    }
}
```

`(new DI())->get('one')->` offers me both **foo** and **bar**

is there a way, how to tell PhpStorm, that if name is one, I well get class `One`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure -- have a look at [Advanced Metadata support](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata).

Please note that this kind of metadata **will only work since PhpStorm v9** (just released yesterday) as v8 only supports static factories.

For example:

```
<?php
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    $STATIC_METHOD_TYPES = [
        \DI::get('') => [
            "foo" instanceof \One,
            "bar" instanceof \Two,
        ]
    ];
}
```

---

**P.S.**

In your code (inside method `get()`) you are using `foo` and `bar` as keys to define what class to create .. but when using actual `DI->get()` you are using class names as keys (e.g. `one`). I'm sure it's just a typo .. but still -- next time try to provide valid code as an example.

Comment: Is there a way, how to declare, that i.e. bar will return array instead of class Two? 

P.S. sorry about the typo.

Comment: TBH -- have no clue. But I doubt about it -- the idea why this "metadata" was created is to complete classes and I guess simple types were left out by default 9considering the syntax). I may only suggest to submit new ticket asking for this at their Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI